# More than one NSFetchedResults Controller allowed in iOS COreData?

Tags: iphone, core-data

Sorry if this is a newbie question.  I'm trying to wrap my head around Core Data.

I have a Tab Bar application where each tab contains a navigation controller.  The top level of each navigation controller is a table that shows a specific and different view of the same set of data, which is in a Core Data store.  This is sort of like iTunes where one Tab shows songs organized by Artist and another shows them organized by title.

My question is where does the NSFetchedResultsController need to live?  Can each navigation controller have its own NSFetchedResultsController and perform fetches in its own unique way or do I have to put the FRC in the app delegate so that both tabs have access to it?  I know the context is in the app delegate so I was thinking this had to be the case here as well.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Why should there be a problem with more than one NSFetchedResultsController? They just fetch data and monitor the context for changes.

You won't experience problems with more than one NSFRController, at least if they live in their own viewController, of course you shouldn't change the same tableView from two different NSFRC delegates.

<strike>I usually disable (i.e. self.frc = nil) the NSFetchedResultsController in the viewWillDisappear method.

Imho there is no need to update five UITableViews if only one is visible.</strike>

Edit: After thinking a little bit about it I come to the conclusion that the performance impact from allocating a new FRC each time the user switches tabs is bigger than updating 5 tableviews. I never checked if the tableViews update their cells when they are not visible anyway.

Comment: I would release (and set nil) the NSFRC in the viewDidUnload. This only gets called when the VC is invisible (and memory becomes scarce) and allows for faster display of the data when switching between viewControllers. Else you would need to also reloadData the tableView to ensure that any changes made to the contexts are made visible.

Comment: you're right. Probably a good idea to change it like you said. I'll file a enhancement request for my app. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct relationship from a NSFetchedResultsController to the app delegate nor a specific view controller.

In general, you will have an FRC that corresponds to a dataset. If this same dataset applies to every VC in you app, you might make the FRC available app wide. If you have many different datasets that are closely related to particular VC, you can make them member variables of that VC.

In the apps I've worked on, I tend to find that one FRC per VC is most common.

Answer (score 0):

NSFetchedResultsController is designed specifically to provide data from Core Data to UITableViews. As such each tableview should have its own controller in the tableview's controller.